# How to get appname from model in django

Tags: python, django

I have this code

```
class Option(models.Model):
  option_text  = models.CharField(max_length=400)
  option_num   = models.IntegerField()
  # add field to hold image or a image url in future

  class Meta:
        app_label = 'myapp'
```

if i have `Options` model in my view i want to get the `appname` from it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(option_instance)
print(ct.app_label)
```

or

```
option_instance._meta.app_label
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an instance of your object, you can quite easily get the app_label from _meta

```
o = Option.objects.all()[0]
print o._meta.app_label
```

There is a host of other usefull information in there. In the shell type help(a._meta) to see them all

Comment: Unless you need the instance, you can just do `Option._meta.app_label`.

Answer (score 0):

**2022**

`app_label = self.__module__.split('.')[0]`

Works in every view scenario.